# Can't mount NFS share across subnets; rpcinfo commands fail from client to server, even when iptables is wide open

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nfs

I apologize in advance for the following novella.

I have a USB drive attached to a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian; crashplan no longer works with Raspbian, sadly, so I can't back it up to my Crashplan server (creatively named "backup").  What I'm trying to do instead is NFS share the filesystem over to my Crashplan server and let it rsync it to a local filesystem, but I can't mount it on the backup server.

"backup" is a CentOS 6 VM running on ESXi, and is in a different subnet than the Pi; I'm using VyOS as a router.  So far, it's generally working great, but I suspect something about VyOS may be screwing up the works.  The VyOS is set up to route between my 10.47.6.0/24 (where the pi is) and 10.47.7.0/24 (where most of my VMs sit).  When I do an rpcinfo from the pi (or from another server in the same subnet), it's successful; when I do it from the other subnet I get:

```
rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection reset by peer
```

It works from the VyOS VM as well.

The pi is the way into my network (my Verizon router forwards certain ports to it for external access), and so iptables is configured to block most things.  However, it's wide open for all ports in my two subnets:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  165.160.2.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     all  --  localhost            anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  10.47.6.0/23         anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  165.160.32.0/24      anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  165.160.2.0/24       anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:http-alt
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
LOGGING    all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain LOGGING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "IPTables-logged: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The VyOS itself has no firewalls configured at all between the two subnets:

```
vyos@vyos:~$ show firewall

-----------------------------
Rulesets Information
-----------------------------
vyos@vyos:~$
```

It has the most basic possible routing configuration:

```
vyos@vyos:~$ show configuration
interfaces {
    ethernet eth0 {
        address 10.47.6.11/24
        duplex auto
        hw-id 00:0c:29:de:e1:e1
        smp_affinity auto
        speed auto
    }
    ethernet eth1 {
        address 10.47.7.1/24
        duplex auto
        hw-id 00:0c:29:de:e1:eb
        smp_affinity auto
        speed auto
    }
    loopback lo {
    }
}
nat {
    source {
        rule 10 {
            outbound-interface eth0
            protocol all
            source {
                address 10.47.7.0/24
            }
            translation {
                address 10.47.7.0/24
            }
        }
    }
}
protocols {
    static {
        route 0.0.0.0/0 {
            next-hop 10.47.6.1 {
                distance 1
            }
        }
    }
}
<snippety snip snip>
```

I can ping all over the place, I can ssh, I can get to web and other services running on the 10.47.7.0/24 VLAN on a variety of ports, so I don't think I have a firewall issue.  More importantly, when I connect an strace to the rpcbind daemon on my pi, *it sees the connection come in* and then dumps it for some reason that I'm not smart enough to translate from the trace data.  This is already 5 times too long so I'll spare you the full strace output, because it's identical before a certain point.

When I successfully connect from the VyOS, the pi says:

```
write(12, "\200\0\2t\16z\37\322\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1"..., 632) = 632
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=9, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=11, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 8, 30000) = 1 ([{fd=12, revents=POLLIN|POLLRDNORM}])
read(12, "", 4)                         = 0
close(12)                               = 0
```

...then it opens a poll to wait for another connection.  When I do it from my backup server:

```
write(12, "\200\0\2t\314\315\372\355\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1"..., 632) = -1 ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
close(12)                               = 0
```

I suppose it could be a firewall issue, but the VyOS has no firewall at all, nor does the backup server; other devices in the same subnet as the backup server can rpcinfo -p backup just fine, and none of them can rpcinfo my pi.  Oddly enough: servers in the 10.47.7 net can rpcinfo servers in the 10.47.6 net *other than the pi*.  But the pi allows connection on any protocol and any port from anything it sees in 10.47.6.0/23 (aka, both subnets), and the strace on rpcbind indicates that it *does* see the incoming connection.  The only thing I can think of is that it's blocking its own outbound connections to 10.47.7.0/24, but I have no outbound rules of any kind and a default ACCEPT policy, and when I flushed the entire table for a quick test I still got failures.  What on earth is going on here?  The pi is listening on all the usual ports:

```
root@splunk:~> rpcinfo -p pi
program vers proto   port  service
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  60044  status
100024    1   tcp  55702  status
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    2   tcp   2049
100227    3   tcp   2049
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    2   udp   2049
100227    3   udp   2049
100021    1   udp  38666  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  38666  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  38666  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  44067  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  44067  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  44067  nlockmgr
100005    1   udp  51123  mountd
100005    1   tcp  57740  mountd
100005    2   udp  39024  mountd
100005    2   tcp  53219  mountd
100005    3   udp  40590  mountd
100005    3   tcp  47949  mountd
```

Argh!!!

Comment: Please use `iptables -L -vn` when listing iptables configs, that includes the interfaces (you might allow 10.47.6.0/23 but from the wrong interface, for example). Also it's usual to place the RELATED,ESTABLISHED line as the first line to prevent lots of matching for known connections.